# How to use @Url.Content within an IF statement in a razor file?

Tags: html, image, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a mvc 4 project where I am using image references that look like this:

```
<img alt="Progress Update" class="projectListNotificationIcon" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/progressUpdateIcon.png")"/>
```

The @Url.Content is necessary for it to work on both the local copy of this project, as well as the live server copy. This works great, however I have another place where I am choosing between 2 different images and tha code looks like this:

```
var imagePath = (item.IsOverdue) ? "../../Images/lateIcon.png" : "../../Images/onTimeIcon.png";
```

How can I use some permutation of the @Url.Content in my if statement above? The current way that I am doing it works in the local project, but not on the server.

Comment: Do you have two seperate image folders?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Nope. But the answer below worked for me.

Comment: With asp.net mvc 4, you don't even need to use `Url.Content()`. Check out this blog post. http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2

Comment: @jessegavin I have tried that as well, and it was not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<img src="@((item.IsOverdue) ? Url.Content("~/path/img1.jpg") : Url.Content("~/path/img2.jpg"))" alt="whatever" />
```

Use of the tilde (~) sign is probably the key, as that resolves the url relative to the root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="@(item.IsOverdue ? "~/path/img1.jpg" : "~/path/img2.jpg")"  />
```

With asp.net mvc 4 urls that begin with the `~` symbol are automatically translated to site relative paths. Read about it here http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2

Comment: Hey anonymous... If you're going to down vote at least give a reason.